# Excel Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf using relative references

Tags: excel, countif, vba

I'll try keep this as simple and nonspecific as I can. I have three columns, a, b, c. Col C has one-hundred random numbers in cells C1-C100. Col A has five random numbers in cells C1:C5.

For each cell B1:B5, I want to enter how many times the number in col a appears in col c. If you were writing the formula directly into cell B1, it would be thus:

> =COUNTIF($C:$C, $A1)

You would then drag down to fill cells B2:B5

I want to do this using VBA's Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf function (my actual project is much more complex than this, and cells need to be filled in automatically).

```
Dim colb As Range
Set colb = Range("$B1:$B5")

Dim colc As Range
Set colc = Range("$C:$C")

Dim cola As Range
Set cola = Range("$A:$A")

For Each bcell In colb
    bcell.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colc, bcell.Offset(0, -1))
Next bcell
```

This works correctly. But I'm wondering if it can be done without a For-Each loop, and without specifying how many cells in B are to be filled in, (recognising when A reaches its last value, and stops filling B in accordingly, a la

```
Dim colb As Range
Set colb = Range("$B:$B")
```

In my mind the crucial line would be something like:

```
colb.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(colc, cola)
```

But this does not work. Is anything I'm asking possible? I imagine letting Excel fill in the whole range at once would be faster than looping.

Answer (score 1):

You could use evaluate:

```
Sub testeval()
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim nARows As Long
Dim nCRows As Long
Dim oSht1 As Worksheet
Dim strSheet As String

Set oSht1 = ActiveSheet
strSheet = oSht1.Name & "!"
nARows = oSht1.Range("A1").Offset(oSht1.Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
nCRows = oSht1.Range("C1").Offset(oSht1.Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
vArr = oSht1.Evaluate("=INDEX(COUNTIF(" & strSheet & "$C1:$C" & CStr(nCRows) & "," & strSheet & "$A1:$A" & CStr(nARows) & "),0,1)")
oSht1.Range("$B1").Resize(UBound(vArr), 1) = vArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop nor do you need to use the worksheetfunction :) This will do that what you want.

```
Range("$B1:$B5").Formula="=COUNTIF($C:$C, $A1)"
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim colb As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set colb = ws.Range("$B1:$B5")

    colb.Formula = "=COUNTIF($C:$C, $A1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: It will, and I considered it. But I have a whole bunch of formulas to write, some of them extremely complex, and I don't have the patience for constructing strings using vb variables. The above is a simple example. The reality is more complex.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a complex formula that you are planning to use?